# SharePoint 2013 "cobalt exception error"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have weird problem with **SharePoint**. I've uploaded a file on a document library and everything seems to be in order. but after a few days the file doesn't work properly and when I try to download it a red label appear with **cobalt exception** message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems your file become corrupted but it doesn't happen it normal situation.
Do you have **Blob Stream** configuration for your SharePoint?

Comment: yeeeah, you're saying this problem because of that?

Comment: as you know Blob Stream make a lots of small file for your file and if just one of them get an issue, your file will be corrupted.

Comment: what a pity, how can I find it out?

Comment: I found it, the problem was because of anti-virus. :)

Comment: that's it. you were lucky.

Comment: @user3424966, what antivirus was that? Was the antivirus on the server side or on the client side? I am facing the same issue right now.